# Share sound in my app

Tags: java, android

My app is a soundboard and I want it is possible that you can share the sounds. This is my code which does not work.

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

Uri recurso = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + PACKAGE_NAME + "/raw/" + R.raw.a);
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, recurso);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.text1)));
```

But the sound can not be sent. What do you have to use as a path where does it have to lead?

pls help me

Comment: I think the correct path is `/res/raw/`.

Comment: The file format is not supported come as error but why?

Comment: Can you please post the error message?

Comment: Share failed please try again. But why? I dont understand this